# How to navigate to a div in another component in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have routeConfig as follows and I am using HashLocationStrategy.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/me', name: 'Profile', component: ProfileComponent}
])
```

How can I navigate to a div(or section) in the profile view (profile#skills) from the Home view using angular2 routing

I would do a href on ***/profile.html#skills*** if it was plain html. I am not sure how to do this in angular2.  May be it is something simple.Appreciate any pointers.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a bug or missing feature in Angular2. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595